# Settings File is corrupted as well as the backup file

Tags: c#, .net, backup, corruption, file-management

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Save settings to config file. Create backup of current settings
    /// </summary>
    public void SaveSettings()
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(CONFIG_DIRECTORY);

        // move current settings file to backup
        if (File.Exists(SettingsFile))
        {
            if (File.Exists(SettingsBackupFile)) // delete prev backup
                File.Delete(SettingsBackupFile);

            File.Move(SettingsFile, SettingsBackupFile);
        }

        // Create new settings file
        using (var f = (TextWriter)File.CreateText(SettingsFile))
        {
            f.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_settings, Formatting.Indented));
            f.Close();
        }
    }
```

I rename the current settings file to a .bak file and then replace the current settings file. I do this because my files can/will become corrupted if the user does a power shutdown during a download. I thought this design pattern would work as I could read from the backup if the settings file is corrupted, but the backup file is becoming corrupted as well.

Comment: What do you think `File.Move(SettingsFile, SettingsBackupFile);` will do if `SettingsFile` was corrupted?

Comment: `my files can/will become corrupted if the user does a power shutdown during a download` But users who do that deserve everything that happens to them.

Comment: @NoneoftheAbove Such a compassionate view you have of end-users who live in areas where power supply is unreliable. :)

Comment: `user does a power shutdown` is not a power outage.

Comment: @mjwills you might be right. I may have incorrectly assumed that if the file became corrupted from a power shutdown then my code wouldn't be executing and thus wouldnt be able to backup a recently corrupted file

Comment: The power goes out, and the settings file is corrupted. Then the next time it runs, you **back up** those corrupted settings to the backup file. _Perhaps consider validating the settings file before backing it up - or keeping more than one backup._

Comment: Yea that must be correct.

Comment: The `StreamWriter` class has a `Flush` method.  Have you tried flushing the file before you close it?

Comment: Does `Close` call `Flush` @Flydog57?

Answer (score 1):

When you write files the data goes into the OS write-back cache. When the OS unexpectedly crashes (power outage, bluescreen, VM kill) that data is lost. The typical symptom is that the file has the correct size but is full of zeroes. (Maybe the size can also be wrong, I don't know.)

Generally, the idea of writing to a new file and then swapping new and old files is a good strategy. But you also need to flush the data to disk.

`FileStream.Flush()` and `StreamWriter.Flush()` do that. So likely, you should add `f.Flush();`.